# Menú se oculta al hacer click en cualquier opción en modo móvil

Tags: c#, blazor

Estoy haciendo una página con blazor, que tiene un menú con submenús,y el cual genero las opciones  dinámicamente. El menú funciona bien a pantalla completa en el ordenador, pero en el móvil cuando pulso un submenú se oculta en vez de mostrar los items y hay que volver a darle al menu para que se despliegue.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando le doy a Profesores, en vez desplegar los items se cierra y hay que volver a darle para mostrar estas opciones.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estas es la parte del código que genera el menú

```html
<div class="top-row pl-4 navbar navbar-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="">Gestion Alumnos</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" @onclick="ToggleNavMenu">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
</div>

<div class="@NavMenuCssClass" @onclick="ToggleNavMenu">
    <ul class="nav flex-column">
        <li class="nav-item px-2">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="" @onclick="() => expandSubProfesores = !expandSubProfesores"  Match="NavLinkMatch.All">
                <span class="oi oi-home" aria-hidden="true"></span> Home
            </NavLink>
        </li>

        @if (profesor == true)
            {
            <li class="nav-item dropdown show px-2">
                <NavLink class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="navbarDropdownProfesor" @onclick="()=>    expandSubProfesores = !expandSubProfesores">
                    <span class="oi oi-people" aria-hidden="true"></span> Profesores
                </NavLink>
                @if (expandSubProfesores)
                    {
                    <ul class="nav flex-column">
                        <li class="nav-item px-3">
                            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="/Matriculas/Index">
                                <span class="oi oi-graph" aria-hidden="true"></span> Informes
                            </NavLink>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item px-3">
                            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="/Seguimientos/ListadoCompletar">
                                <span class="oi oi-task" aria-hidden="true"></span> Seguimientos
                            </NavLink>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item px-3">
                            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="/Reservas/Reserva">
                                <span class="oi oi-clock" aria-hidden="true"></span> Reserva de Espacios
                            </NavLink>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    }
            </li>
            }
```

Este comportamiento es el mismo para tutores, equipo directivo, etc.
Como se puede hacer para que el menú no se oculte al darle a un submenu?
Seguro que es una tontería, pero no doy.

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Pues al final era efectivamente una tontearía, pero bueno por si a alguien le interesa, el "problema" esta en esta línea, que hace que cada vez que pulses algo dentro del div, el menú se cierre,

```html
<div class="@NavMenuCssClass" @onclick="ToggleNavMenu">
```

Quitando el evento onclick y poniéndolo en cada NavLink funciona perfectamente.

El código que así

```html
<div class="@NavMenuCssClass">
    <ul class="nav flex-column">
        <li class="nav-item px-2">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="" Match="NavLinkMatch.All">
                <span class="oi oi-home" aria-hidden="true"></span> Home
            </NavLink>
        </li>

        @if (profesor == true)
            {
            <li class="nav-item dropdown show px-2">
                <NavLink class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" @onclick="() => expandSubProfesores = !expandSubProfesores" id="navbarDropdown">
                    <span class="oi oi-people" aria-hidden="true"></span> Profesores
                </NavLink>
                @if (expandSubProfesores)
                    {
                    <ul class="nav flex-column">
                        <li class="nav-item px-3">
                            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="/Matriculas/Index"  @onclick="ToggleNavMenu">
                                <span class="oi oi-graph" aria-hidden="true"></span> Informes Cualitivos
                            </NavLink>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item px-3">
                            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="/Seguimientos/ListadoCompletar">
                                <span class="oi oi-task" aria-hidden="true"  @onclick="ToggleNavMenu"></span> Seguimientos
                            </NavLink>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item px-3">
                            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="/Reservas/Reserva"  @onclick="ToggleNavMenu">
                                <span class="oi oi-clock" aria-hidden="true"></span> Reserva de Espacios
                            </NavLink>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    }
            </li>
            }
```